Customtkinter: не отображается таблица в ScrollableFrame
У меня проблема: таблица не отображается в ScrollableFrame
Кусок кода:
import customtkinter as ctk
from CTkTable import *
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("marks.db")
curs = conn.cursor()
grade = "4А"

root = ctk.CTk()
root.title("Редактирование оценок")
root.geometry("1000x250")

studentsTableList = [["Число"],
                    ["Тип работы"]]

marksTableList = [[""],
                  [""]]

curs.execute("SELECT name FROM students WHERE grade == ?", (grade,))
students1 = curs.fetchall()
students2 = []
print(students1)

for student in students1:
    students2.append(student)
for student in students2:
    studentsTableList.append([student])
    marksTableList.append([""])

tip = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="Нажмите на колёсико для добавления урока").place(x=0, y=0)

frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(root, orientation="horizontal", width=600, fg_color="transparent")
frame.place(x=300, y=28)

studentsTable =CTkTable(frame, values=studentsTableList, width=300)
studentsTable.place(x=0, y=28)

marksTable = CTkTable(root, values=marksTableList, write=1)
marksTable.place(x = 300, y = 28)

...

root.mainloop()

Скриншот (с frame):

Хотя если я уберу frame (буду размещать таблицу в главном окне), то она спокойно отобразится:

*на изображении frame я не убирал, но таблица отображается в главном окне

Решение: place не используется с frame. Я использовал grid.
